# Destructors in inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor

I have got doubt when I was going through the code below. I.e why the destructor of derived class is not called even when an object of derived class goes out of scope in the code below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class ClassA
{
    protected:
        int width, height;
    public:
      void set_values(int x, int y)
      {
        width = x;
        height = y;
      }
      virtual int area()
      {
        return 0;
      }
      ~ClassA()
      {
         cout << "base class destructor called" << endl;
      }
 };

class ClassB : public ClassA
{
      public :
   int area()
   {
     return (width * height);
   }
   ~ClassB()
       {
      cout << "derived class destructor called" << endl;
   }
 };


 int main()
 {
   ClassA *Ptr = NULL;
   ClassB Obj;
   Ptr = &Obj;
   Ptr->set_values(10, 20);
   cout << Ptr->area() << endl;
   delete Ptr;
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not call `delete` on Base class pointer pointing to derived class object unless the base class destructor is `virtual` else what you get is **Undefined Behavior**.

The destructor in base class needs to be marked `virtual`.

```
virtual ~ClassA(){}
```

Comment: Even if the destructor is virtual, it's *still* undefined behavior to call `delete` on a pointer that points to a local variable.

Comment: @SteveJessop: True that! I missed it

Comment: @Steve : Then we should not delete the pointer , just we have declare and use it ...?

Comment: @nagaradderKantesh: You only call `delete` when there was a `new` called not otherwise. What you have is an pointer pointing to local/automatic object. An automatic object gets destroyed automatically when the scope `{ }` in which it is declared ends. It does not need explicit deallocation.

Comment: @Alok Save: then if i have not delete the pointer it will still hold the address of object that leads to memory leak na ..?

Comment: @nagaradderKantesh: memory leak is only relevant for dynamically allocated objects. Local/automatic objects are automatically deallocated when scope ends.

Answer (score 1):

Make your destructor `virtual` in base class. Otherwise, it calls base's destructor.

```
class ClassA
{
// ...
      virtual ~ClassA()
      {
         cout << "base class destructor called" << endl;
      }
};
```

Comment: yeah i know that ..but after deleting ptr base class destructor will call and then control goes to return and out of program  means it is out of scope (derived class object 'Obj' will go out of scope ) but even though derived class object Obj went out of scope scope why destructor of derived class not called.

Comment: @nagaradderKantesh: "and then control goes to return" -- you have invoked undefined behavior. You don't get to say where control goes next, because if there's undefined behavior anywhere, the behavior of the *whole program* is undefined.